# No modules shown in JSDoc/docdash

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, es6-modules

I use JSDoc 3.5.4 with the docdash 0.4.0 theme but contrary to the [docdash screenshots](http://clenemt.github.io/docdash/), I am missing the **MODULES** section despite using the @module tag as described in http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html.
Instead all my code is listed under **GLOBAL**. How can I generate the **MODULES** section?

### Example Module foo.js

```
//** @module */
import * as log from "./log.js"
/** Example JSDOC. */
export function foo() {log.info("foo");}
```

### Example Module bar.js

```
//** @module */
import * as log from "./log.js"
/** Example JSDOC. */
export function bar() {log.info("bar");}
```

Now I expect the foo and bar methods to be grouped in their particular module, but they are both lumped together in **GLOBAL**.

I execute jsdoc via `node_modules/.bin/jsdoc js -c jsdoc.json` and my `jsdoc.json` contains:

```
{"opts": {"template": "node_modules/docdash"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the JSDoc comment for the modules `//**` was wrong, it works with `/**`,